# Simulator and Device Testing Fails - Sends Request to Google, Not My App

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

This is an issue that began yesterday, for me and my team.

When I invoke my draft agent in google assistant and then send a query, the query gets sent to the normal Google Assistant to do a web search, instead of my agent. My agent then closes.

For example:

- "Talk to Agent" - invokes the agent and welcome intent
- "What's the temperature" closes the agent and searches Google for the temperature.

This also happens with commands that Google does not have its own response for - I get a google search outside my agent.

This does not happen on other platforms, such as Facebook Messenger and the Dialogflow console, but does occur in the Actions on Google simulator.

Comment: Can you share logs for Google Assistant? Open the Google project --> Logs --> Google Assistant and see where it is failing

Comment: Are you seeing this in the simulator? If so, adding screen shots of the simulator at each stage of the conversation will help us, particularly if you also include the contents of the Debug (and pssibly request and response) tabs at each stage.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi There seem to be no logs, no command is reaching firebase or GCP. (There are no errors in the simulator either, it thinks it's doing what it's meant to.

Comment: @Prisoner https://i.imgur.com/btQwSha.png These are 2 'debug' commands which should trigger an intent. They previously worked fine, I changed nothing now this happens. In the app on my phone, it literally calls benares, and does a google search for 01001

Comment: Please verify these 2 items - (a) by any chance instead of app.ask or conv.ask you are using app.tell or conv.close  (b) internet and wifi connectivity is good and not fluctuating.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi Internet connection fine - same issue across devices and networks. I'm using agent.add.

Comment: @Prisoner Sorry, forgot the logs - https://imgur.com/a/1iWRovz

Comment: If you are sharing the assistant with team members, try this once... on the simulator go to share (top right) --> permissions --> reassign permission to the users --> copy the simulator link --> share the link with testers --> ask every tester to open this link on the browser once and then do the testing. See if this works.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi I need to get it working for myself, the owner of the project and organisation admin first!

Comment: From the screen shot of the simulator, it looks like its working, although it is difficult to tell since the voice-only response is limited and you're not showing the device screen tab. If you can show everything that the simulator is showing, not just the conversation part, we may get a better idea what is happening. Or are you saying it works in the simulator but not your device?

Comment: @Prisoner I don't think I explained it right. I have an intent that responds to 'call Benares.' It does not actually call the number, my app has it's own response to that. When I say that to the agent, it leaves my dialogflow agent, and google asssitant itself calls Benares's phone number from google maps. In the simulator, the display is blank and says 'Master Agent' - my agent, has left the conversation. None of my intents are triggering at all any more, it just defaults back to Google Assistant itself. Here is a screen recording of it on my phone to illustrate: https://streamable.com/sm5qq

Comment: @Prisoner To clarify, it doesn't work on device or the simulator, on multiple devices and accounts. (This is the correct response in Facebook messenger - it's calling the same code, the same databases, the same dialogflow agent: https://imgur.com/a/LK9UHsJ )

Comment: Ok, I still haven't seen an image of it NOT working. The shot you posted above looks like it worked, but it was difficult to tell since you didn't show the entire simulator screen.

Comment: @Prisoner Hi, sorry for all the confusion here, thanks for your help I appreciate it as this is a bizarre issue. I have screen recorded the simulator here https://streamable.com/xdm36. Please compare that with the facebook agent. Google Assistant used to respond exactly like the facebook agent. https://imgur.com/a/LK9UHsJ. The bot is not triggering my intent, it's asking Google, as if I haven't invoked my agent.

Comment: Ok. That helps a lot. Can you also either do that with the "Debug" tab active or after each response also switch to the "Request" "Response" and "Debug" tabs? You're using the same fulfillment code for both the Facebook bot and the Assistant agent? Are you doing this with a fulfillment webhook? If so, can you update the question to show what some of the code that is sending back strange responses look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176417/discussion-between-nathan-liu-and-prisoner).

Comment: Are you using Google account (@gmail.com) for your Google assistant or some different? Recently, someone had wired issue where even the sample agents were not working for him. Once he created a different project using Gmail account and exported the Dialogflow agent to that, then it started working. You may try to export your agent to a new one and give a try on a different project.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi I'm using a G Suite account. I'll try accessing with another account and see, I have access to the google admin panel to so I'll check there!

Comment: When you launch your second intent, Does the first one have an exit context?